# Upload picture to SQL using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to upload a picture from the computer to a Windows application and insert it into a SQL database. I'm using Entity Framework - how can I do it?

Comment: save file into folder with guid and store in sql as guid  as string

Comment: Break the problem into two pieces 1) Upload and image 2) Store an image in the database.  The answer glassVoid geek provided is uploading the image as a Base64 String and storing the image as Base64 String.  You may want to store the image in binary instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

If the database of this application is only running on a single system(locally), you can save file path in database. If its on a remote system, then convert image to byte array and store it in DB.

[Click this link it would be helpful for you](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/2f55345c-1fcb-4262-89f4-c4319f95c5bd.aspx)